# I am printing the number of lines, words, and characters from a file but my output is inconsistent with all the online word and character counter

Tags: python, python-3.x

File contents link : https://textdoc.co/IipN4yOLUQkwmMx8

Code snippet :

```
file = open('ramji.txt','r')
no_of_lines, no_of_words, no_of_chars = 0,0,0
for x in file:
    no_of_lines+=1
    no_of_words+=len(x.split(' '))
    no_of_chars+=len(x.strip())
print(f'No. of lines are :{no_of_lines}\nNo.of words are :{no_of_words}\nNo. of characters are :{no_of_chars}')
```

output:

```
No. of lines are :10
No.of words are :79
No. of characters are :389
```

On checking the number of words and characters on an online word counter, the words are coming out to be `78` and characters are `390`

Answer (score 0):

On line 9 of your text file, there is a space in the following:
"Cows called mother in India. "

Your code goes through each line in your file, `ramji.txt` and strips out the extra space, which is how you obtained `78` instead of `79` words. The `strip()` function removed the space, so you ended up with `398` instead of `399` words.

Below is how to count the lines, words, and characters the way the online word counter did. Simply remove `.strip()` and you will get the matching result.

```
file = open('ramji.txt','r')
no_of_lines, no_of_words, no_of_chars = 0,0,0

#print(file.read())

for x in file:
    no_of_lines+=1
    no_of_words+=len(x.split(' '))
    no_of_chars+=len(x)
    
    line = x.split(" ")
    print(line, len(line))
  
print(f'No. of lines are :{no_of_lines}\nNo.of words are :{no_of_words}\nNo. of characters are :{no_of_chars}')
```

[image: Replit Screenshot]